# Error Type mismatch: inferred type is View! but String was expected

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, one-time-password

I don't know why I doing wrong, I get this error
"Type mismatch: inferred type is View! but String was expected"

the line that give me the Error is about the "otp"

this is the code:

```
      binding!!.otpView.setOnClickListener { otp ->
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId!!,otp)
        auth!!.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val intent = Intent(this@OTPActivity, SetupProfileActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finishAffinity()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@OTPActivity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, please pay attention to  tag descriptions. The [`erlang-otp` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/erlang-otp/info) is not related at all to what you're asking about; I've edited your tags to replace it with the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

> the line that give me the Error is about the "otp"

There are two lines in your code that contain that symbol:

```kotlin
      binding!!.otpView.setOnClickListener { otp ->
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId!!,otp)
```

If `PhoneAuthProvivder` is the one from Firebase, then [the second parameter to `getCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider#getCredential(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is supposed to be a `String`. However, `otp` is a `View`, as that is how `OnClickListener` works. So, instead of passing `otp` to `getCredential()`, you need to get some value out of `otp` that represents what you are supposed to give to `getCredential()`. According to Firebase, that is supposed to be "the 6 digit SMS-code sent to the user". If `otp` represents some sort of OTP/PIN view, hopefully it has a function to get what the user typed in, and you will need to call that function and pass its value to `getCredential()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake
I use the:

```
binding!!.otpView.setOnClickListener { otp ->
```

but i need to use that:

```
 binding!!.otpView.setOtpCompletionListener { otp ->
```